# How to watch controller scope in directives?

Tags: angularjs

Am stuck with some basic issues. Can any one point me out whats going wrong ?

My controller is like

```
angular.module('asApp').controller('searchCtrl', ['$scope', 'service', 
        function($scope, AppService) {

axisAPI.object()
     .app(service.app())
     .qId('abcd')
     .on('create',function(object) {
         object.paint();
     }).on('paint',function(data){
         $scope.$apply(function(){
                                $scope.profileObk = data.profile;
                                $scope.contactObj= data.profile;
          })
     }).create();
});
```

and my directive is

```
angular.module('app.core')
.directive('contactPage', DirectiveFunction2 );
function DirectiveFunction2 ($scope,config,service) {

var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
    controller: function($scope){
     $scope.newContacts = undefined;

    $scope.$watch("contactObj", function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal==oldVal) {
            return false;
        }
        $scope.newContacts = newVal;
    }, );

}
    link:function (scope, element, attrs) {}
  }
    return directive;
}
```

my HTML

```
<div ng-controller="searchCtrl"> </div>
<contact-page></contact-page>
```

If the value is updated from on "searchCtrl" it should be changed in my directives. How to do that. "searchCtrl" is a third party controller.

Answer (score 0):

`$watch` worked as expected. See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/gv8u51L0/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.parentModel = {
      val: ""
    };
  })
  .directive('exampleDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        parentModel: "@",
        linkController: "@"
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        var anotherScope = angular.element(document.querySelector("*[ng-controller='"+$scope.linkController+"']")).scope();
        $scope.$watch(function() {
          return anotherScope[$scope.parentModel];
        }, function(newVal) {
          console.log('newVal', newVal);
        }, true);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input ng-model="parentModel.val"> {{parentModel}}
  </div>
  <example-directive link-controller="ExampleController" parent-model="parentModel"></example-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: Actaully my directive is out of the controller. Not inside the controller

Comment: @user2587222 If the directive outside the controller , you can try the following method. I'm update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Can any one point me out whats going wrong ?

The directive is trying to inject `$scope` in the directive constructor function. There should have been an error displayed in the console.

The `$scope` is not injectable in the directive constructor function.

```
angular.module('app.core')
.directive('contactPage', DirectiveFunction2 );
//$scope not injectable here
//function DirectiveFunction2 ($scope,config,service) {
//
//Only providers are injectable
function DirectiveFunction2 (config,service) {

var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
    //$scope is injected as a local by $compile service
    controller: function($scope){
     $scope.newContacts = undefined;

    $scope.$watch("contactObj", function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal==oldVal) {
            return false;
        }
        $scope.newContacts = newVal;
    }, );

}
    link:function (scope, element, attrs) {}
  }
    return directive;
}
```

The `$scope` is provided only as a **local** to the directive controller constructor function by the `$compile` service.

From the Docs:

> ### Controller constructor function.
>
> The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase and can be accessed by other directives (see require attribute). This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior. The controller is injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the following **locals**:
>
> - $scope - Current scope associated with the element
> - $element - Current element
> - $attrs - Current attributes object for the element
> - $transclude - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope: `function([scope], cloneLinkingFn, futureParentElement, slotName)`

-- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API -- controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-)

Comment: I deleted the $scope. No errors  now. Is it possible to watch variable from controller in directives

Comment: Yes, you can watch scope variables in directives. The code looks like it should work. What problems are you having?

Comment: I have placed my directive outside controller. Will it work still ?

Comment: There are different ways to communicate data between sibling scopes. I generally recommend using a service.